# Using a microcontroller to drive an ignition coil

Tags: microcontroller, coil, igbt

I am building an Arduino/Speeduino-based ignition controller and want to drive a 12 V coil from a digital output of the ATmega2560.

Below is my design for a coil driver using an IGBT (NGD8205ANT4G) with an isolated IGBT driver (UCC21520). I used the UCC21520 evaluation module schematic for component values.

Does this solution look like it would work?

[image: IGBT Ignition coil driver]

**Edit. Revised components and layout:**

[image: IGBT driver]

Comment: Why use an isolated driver?

Comment: @Andyaka - My thinking is that would help limit the EMF getting back to the uC from the coil driving side?

Comment: Well, you have a common ground on both sides and back emf from coils is usually solved at the coils - maybe you need to extend your circuit to show the coil(s)?

Comment: @Andyaka Is there a disadvantage in using an isolated driver?

Comment: Cost, reliability, random malfunction.

Comment: NGD8205ANT4G is only 350V.  High enough voltage for your ignition?  I actually kind of like using the isolated driver if you run separate, low current ground paths back to VSSA and VSSB to from the individual emitters of the IGBTs.  (Do not tie them together at U7).

Answer (score 1):

Isolation is lost because you have tied the grounds on both sides of the driver together.

You should rethink about using 51 ohm pulldown termination on the driver inputs. Few microcontrollers can drive a load like that to a decent high level without extra stress on the output circuit of the MCU.

Comment: Indeed I realise the isolation is lost - I will replace that component with a non-isolated version and replace the pull ups with something like a 1K resistor.

Comment: Pull downs, rather.